# How to display command history with jline3?

Tags: jline, jline3

I want the most recent command entered to be displayed when the user presses the up arrow key.

The `Terminal` is defined like this (Scala code):

```
val terminal: Terminal =
  TerminalBuilder.builder
    .system(true)
    .build
```

The `LineReader` is defined like this:

```
def reader(parser: Parser, terminal: Terminal): LineReader = {
  val lineReader: LineReader = LineReaderBuilder.builder
    .terminal(terminal)
    .completer(shellManager.topShell.completer)
    .parser(parser)
    .variable(LineReader.HISTORY_FILE, historyFile)
    .history(new DefaultHistory())
    .build

  lineReader.unsetOpt(LineReader.Option.INSERT_TAB)
  lineReader
}
```

Update: I found that the above actually works on some consoles, not others. I am still discovering what works and what does not. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to work out-of-the box.  If you have an issue with a specific terminal, please report which exact terminal you use.  For what it's worth, this can't work from inside build tools (gradle, maven) or IDE (Eclipse, Intellij IDEA).